# Understanding the 'stop-stutter' movements of Emiko in The Windup Girl

Tags: paolo-bacigalupi, the-windup-girl

In The Windup Girl by Paolo Bacigalupi, Emiko is a 'new person', genetically engineered, a 'windup'.

To mark her as such, so that no-one will ever mistake her for a 'normal person', she has a particular form of motion common to all such 'windups'.

I am having trouble visualising/understanding this motion. It is often mentioned it is meant to accentuate her movement, that she is graceful. It is also mentioned that military windups, who are superior fighters also have this movement. So clearly it does not impair them. Yet the talk of 'stop-stutter' movements suggests tremors or a chameleons back and forth hesitation before putting its foot down, and neither of these mesh with superior fighters or grace.

Additionally, this book is entwined with ideas of genetic engineering and climate change, it is, I think hard science fiction, thus there should be some basis for how such movement was instilled in the genetic sense. For example, the Megadonts of the book are engineered mammoth-elephant type animals that with advances in Genetics we could potentially engineer.

So my question is twofold:

- Is there any information on how the author imagined the movement would have been introduced?
- Are there any sources or ideas that reconcile how the movement is so obvious but still allows superior military windups etc.

Some direct quotes on her movement:

- > “stutter-stop flash-bulb strange”
- > "She pushes damp hair away from her face. A surreal stutter-stop motion, the genetic bits of her unkinking."
- > "She moves her hand. Telltale stutter-stop motion. "I am marked. Always, we are marked. As obvious as a ten-hands or a megodont.""

The derogatory term of 'herky-jerky' and 'windup' also refer to this movement.

Comment: Is it possible for you to include some quotations of descriptions of this style of movement?

Comment: @Spagirl I have done so, however, the author is not expansive, and tends to use the same terminology throughout.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. You originally said that 'it is meant to accentuate her movement, that she is graceful.' is it possible to expand on the gracefulness aspect? What I am imagining at present is like a cross between stop motion animation and the movement of clockwork automata, which most would probably not decribe as 'graceful', though 'herky-jerky' would apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insofar as I thought about it, I took Emiko to be moving like the sudden stop/start action of a [fast lizard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joR4OL_mQnE). Graceful, but full of sudden acceleration and deceleration too fast for the normal human eye. This lizard-like quality is also suggested by the way she overheats and depends on swimming to cool later in the book.

However, there is a little more detail on his inspiration in this interview, and it's not lizards:

> As far as Emiko's original inspiration, she came to me during an international flight. A Japanese stewardess caught my eye, because she was moving with a strange sort of herky-jerky motion. I almost thought she was acting a role because the movements were so robotically stylized. I couldn't get the image out of my head.

-- Interview with Bacigalupi in [*Rain Taxi*](https://www.raintaxi.com/the-author-with-the-unpronounceable-name-an-interview-with-paolo-bacigalupi/)

This suggests something like the stylized, graceful, but also pause-filled stop-start movement of [kabuki theatre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93XctajE1Xw), or the [robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IPAOxrH7Ro).